# Show $f(x) := \cos(\root\of{|x|})$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Clearly it isn't, a quick sketch would show it, but I need an analytical proof. The obvious suggestion would be to view the limit on both sides and try to find a inconsistency but how does that work exactly in this case.

Evaluating from both sides the definition of differentiability yields already an intuition as to why this won't work:

If $x > 0$:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\root\of{|x|}) - 1}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\root\of{x}) - 1}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\root\of{x}) - 1}{x} \lt 0$$
If $x<0$:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\root\of{|x|}) - 1}{x-0}= \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\root\of{(-x)}) - 1}{x-0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos(\root\of{(-x)}) - 1}{x} \ge 0$$

But I'm sure this is not rigorous enough. Wondering if someone could direct me to how to finish this properly. Thanks.

Comment: That works. Right and left limit don't match.

Comment: From what is here, you have not yet convinced me that those limits do not equal 0.

Comment: I see what you mean @DougM, perhaps I should think about creating bounds somehow.

Comment: Also, $\sqrt{-x}$ should be $\sqrt{x}$ because of the absolute value :) so its enough to say that the function is definitely an odd function and therefore the limit is undefined at zero.

Comment: Mhmm I don't think so, x is negative which creates problems when interacting with square roots.

Comment: You have $\cos \sqrt {|x|}$ in the problem header.  And is your problem isn't that you have negative numbers under the radical.  You should try to evaluate the limits and show that the right hand limit equal $\frac 12$ while the left hand limit equals $-\frac 12$

Comment: Indeed it's in the header, I'm merely applying the definition of absolute value. So no, you cannot just switch $-x$ to $x$ when $x < 0$.

Answer (score 1):

What you've done is totally fine. Remember, something is only differentiable if it is continuous and these two limits are the same:

$$ L_r = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0^+} {f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) \over \Delta x} $$
$$ L_l = \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0^-} {f(x+\Delta x) - f(x) \over \Delta x} $$

It is sufficient to show, in any way, that the two limits are not the same; which you've done, so I think its rigorous enough! You're right to say that the left limit is positive and the right limit is negative (-0.5 and 0.5 respectively)

## Increasing Clarity

I see a few issues here, so lets start with this, you want to show that:

$$ \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0^+} { \cos\sqrt{ \Delta x} - 1 \over \Delta x} \ne - \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0^+} { \cos\sqrt {\Delta x} - 1 \over \Delta x} $$

So unless the limit is zero, you can show that its non-differentiable. Can you see a way to show that this limit is not zero? (Perhaps try a taylor series)

Comment: "$\Delta x\to\infty$" -- what???

Comment: oops... 0 :P let me fix that - thanks

Comment: Your answer is still wrong. $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\cdots$ does not give the left-sided limit; it is a two-sided limit. What you meant to write is
$$L_r=\lim_{\Delta x\to0^{\color{red}{+}}}\cdots$$
and
$$L_\ell=\lim_{\Delta x\to0^{\color{red}{-}}}\cdots$$

Comment: Yes, I agree; I really should be more careful :P but it should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

If I were grading your solution for absolute "rigor," I'd wonder how you'd prove that the one-sided limits are negative and positive, respectively. As it is, you simply assert the difference in sign, but you do not defend those assertions.

To make that analysis explicit, you could either use L'Hopital's rule or the Taylor series for cosine. Which approach you should use depends on what you've learned.

To use the Taylor series, for example, just note

$$\cos(\sqrt{x})=1-(\sqrt{x})^2/2+O(\sqrt{x}^4)$$

so

$$\frac{1}{x}(\cos(\sqrt{x}-1)=-\frac{1}{2}+O(x)$$

etc.

Comment: using those big ohs is too fancy

Comment: @JimmySabater: it's not too "fancy." Your solution does not *show* that the limit does not exist. You just repeat the OP's error. You must *defend* that assertion.

Comment: big ohs are really hard to grasp for beginners.. I dont know but I also (to be brutally honest) I also feel inconfortable when I see those ohs

Comment: You don't need to write the big ohs if, for whatever reason, they make you uncomfortable (not "inconfortable"): it is just the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ substituted by $\sqrt{x}$. Or, as I said, use L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

We can argue that $f(x)=\cos(\sqrt{|x|} )$ is differentiable for $x<0$ and for $x>0$ we find that in both these cases

$f'(x)= -\operatorname{sgn}\left(x\right)\frac{\sin\left(\sqrt{\left|x\right|}\right)}{2\sqrt{\left|x\right|}}$

Then we can evaluate $$\lim_{x\to0^-}{f'(x)=}\frac{1}{2}\neq-\frac{1}{2}=\lim_{x\to0^+}{f'(x)}$$
Because these don't match we know that $f$ is not differentiable for $x=0$.

Essentially, we can exploit the fact that $f$ is differentiable for $x\neq0$ to demonstrate that $f$ is not differentiable for $x=0$.

Comment: We can find $f'$ by using chain rule.

Comment: I reckon this may be a bit hoppy. I can foresee that my claim that $f$ is differentiable when $x\not=0$ would have to be proven **by definition** which would turn out to be a very long and difficult proof.